# Probability that a random binary matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, random-matrices

What is the probability that a random $\{0,1\}$, $n \times n$ matrix is invertible?
Assume the 0 and 1 are each present in an entry with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.
Is there an explicit formula as a function of $n$?  Does it tend to 1 as $n$ grows large?
I'm sure this is all known...

Thanks!

Comment: Over which ring do you mean? $\mathbb F_2$, $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @joriki: I meant over $\mathbb{R}$, but you are right, there are several questions here...

Comment: Tao and Vu have looked at the problem over $\mathbf R$.  The probability tends toward 1, but an exact formula isn't known. Here's a quote from the abstract of Tao and Vu's paper: "We show that the probability that $M_n$ is singular is at most $(3/4 +o(1))^n$..."  The preprint is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501313).  The paper appeared in JAMS.

Comment: @Will: I think they examine $\{-1,+1\}$ matrices...?

Comment: You are correct, but the answer is the same for both problems. There's a 1-1 map from $n\times n$ $\{-1,1\}$ matrices normalized so that the first row and column are all ones and $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ $\{1,0\}$ matrices.  Under this map, the determinant changes by a factor of $2^{1-n}$.

Comment: Incidentally, the result that the singularity probability tends toward zero is due to Komlos.  See Tao and Vu's earlier [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411095) for the history of the problem.

Comment: @Joseph: this was discussed on MO at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices .

Comment: @Will & Qiaochu: Thank you!  The MO posting is quite informative.

Answer (score 22):

Here's the answer over $\mathbb F_2$; I don't know about other rings:

The first row vector has a $1$ in $2^n$ chance to be linearly dependent, the second $2$ in $2^n$ and so on, so the probability for an $n\times n$ matrix to be invertible is

$$p(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-2^{-k})\;,$$

and the limit is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}p(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-2^{-k})\approx0.288788$$

as [calculated by W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Prod%5B1-2%5E%28-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D).

Comment: Interesting!  Let's call that joriki's number. :-)

Comment: I can't resist: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem

Comment: @Joseph: I strengthened my claim to it by using it in [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219552/probability-that-a-sequence-repeats-itself/219978#219978). :-)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Turns out the number already had [an OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A048651) in $2007$, so no claim to a name, I'm afraid :-)