# How many invertible 3x3 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

How many invertible $ 3 \times 3 $ matrices exist over $2$-element field?

---

Obviously if some field has only $2$ elements, those elements must be $0$ and $1$. 
A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is non zero. I think it will be easier to find matrices which determinants are $0$ and subtract that number from $2^9$ (total number of matrices we can build over that field).

Is there any "clever" way of solving this problem?

Comment: Hint: it will be invertible precisely when the columns are linearly independent. So after picking the first column, how many can you pick for the next? And the next?

Comment: You can probably find several older related questions, for example: [Number of invertible 0-1 matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127489), [Probability that a random binary matrix is invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54246) or [Consider the set of all $n\times n$ matrices, how many of them are invertible modulo $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118080).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^3-2^0=7$ choices for the first row as nozero vector.
Then $2^3-2^1=6$ choices for the second row vector not in the span of the first.
Then $2^3-2^2=4$ choices for the third row not in the span of the first two.

Comment: Wouldn't the second choice be only 5 ?  Zero is exclude d, the first row is excluded, and the first row + first row is excluded.

Comment: @Shailesh There cannot be first row + first row, since field has only two elements I think

Comment: @luka5z. Yes.Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Here we are finding invertible matrices:

None of columns can be entirely zero and the columns must linearly independent. We can construct the first in $2^3$ ways but $(0,0,0)$ is included so we are left with $8-1=7$ ways for the first column. Now again we can construct the second column in $2^3$ ways but $(0,0,0)$ and the arrangement of type of first column should be excluded for linear independence; thus for second column we are left with $8-2=6$ ways; similarly for third column we have $8-1{(0,0,0)}-1$(first column)$-1$ (second column)$-1$ (span of first two columns)$= 4$.

Thus, the total no. of ways = total number of invertible matrices = 7×6×4 = 168.

Comment: Why the 1, for the span of first two columns? Some more detail there would be appreciated, possibly explaining in a way without using 'span'

Comment: For third column excluded columns are 1) 0C1+0C2= 0. 2) 1C1+0C2= C1. 3) 0C1+1C2=Ç2. 4) 1C1+1C2= C1+ C2

Comment: @AshokSinghBhandari It can be proven that from 8 possible choices for a row, one and only one of them is in the set {(C1+C2), (C1−C2), (C2−C1)}. So the fourth linear composition you mentioned should be one the above compositions not just what you wrote.