# Probability of a matrix having determinant zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, probability-theory

What would be the probability of matrix having determinant zero out of all matrices with all entries being positive? How does one calculate such?

Edit: Restriction to natural numbers and size of $n \times n$. Restriction to entries from 0 to 5 or from 0 to 10.

Comment: How are the entries chosen? If from the reals with independent uniforms on $[0,1]$ say, the probability is $0$. Indeed the answer is $0$ for any independent random variables with any continuous distribution.

Comment: You can't answer this question unless you know what the distribution is.

Comment: Even with your edit, you still can't answer it unless you know the probability that each number occurs.

Comment: After my edit, is this answerable? Oh.. but then distribution... OK, I will provide distribution.

Comment: The distribution(s) you chose seem(s) to eliminate all hope of an underlying structure to the problem.

Comment: For an example of a version of this question that has a simple answer, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54246.

Answer (score 0):

If the possible elements belong to an infinite set such as natural numbers, real numbers or complex numbers, then the probability is 0 simply because the space of matrices with determinant 0 is a subspace of all matrices.

If they belong to a finite set, then the probability is between 0 and 1 but most likely so small and gets even smaller as your set grows.